# how can i tweet text with apstrophe

Tags: html, twitter

text with apstrophe is not working in the twitter. Now i am using this character code( %26%2339%3B ) for apstrophe. It's working fine in facebook but it's not working in twitter, and it's showing like this 9 Tandra's plant nursery, Golapi's bag making business and more in our Success Story Digest http://www.rangde.org/success-stories/january-2012/jan-2012.html ). my html is              my js fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/yDyjn/)

Comment: Use `%27` instead of the url-encoded version of `&#39;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%26%2339%3B` translates to `&#39;`. You seem to misunderstand the principle of HTML entities / url encoding.

The following table describes what's going to happen:

```
href= *        Property     URL-decoded 
%26%2339%3B    #26%2339%3B  &#39;        
%27            %27          '            
&#39;          '            '            
'              '            '            Safe ONLY IF `href` is not marked with '
                                                    (as in `<a href='...'..'>`)

*href        = Literal attribute value, as seen when viewing the source
*Property    = The real value of the attribute, after parsing HTML
*URL-decoded = As received at the server's side, or through   decodeURI
```

So, use `'`, `%27` or `&#39;` instead of `%26%2339%3B`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT AFTER FEEDBACK

Try `&#39;`.

Comment: -1 for an incorrect answer. `&#154;` translates to `š`, which is NOT an apostrophe. I'd suggest to delete this answer, to avoid more downvotes.

Comment: I have removed my downvote, because the answer is not incorrect any more. it does however, not contain any explanatation about *why* / *how* it should be used, neither the reasons for it.